# Wordpress BODY class - add page slug as body class AND make it the first class

Tags: wordpress, function, class, slug

The standard 'Add page slug as body class' function page is good.
How to make the class(es) appear first in the list displayed in the body tag?

E.g. Currently: <body *class="page-template page-template-main page-template-main-php page page-id-XXXX **page-main**"*>

Change to: <body *class="**page-main** page-template page-template-main page-template-main-php page page-id-XXXX"*>

Original code:

```
// ADD PAGE SLUG TO BODY CLASS
function add_page_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    
    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'page-' . $post->post_name;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_page_slug_body_class' );
```

Comment: Use `return array_reverse( $classes );` instead of `return $classes;`. It will reverse the array items. But just curious. Does the order of classes in the HTML tag matter?

Answer (score 0):

Though the position of the class name does not play any significant role, it can achieved from below code.

```
<?php

function add_page_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    
    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        // $classes[] =  $post->post_name;
        array_unshift($classes, $post->post_name); // using array_unshift will insert the data at index 0
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_page_slug_body_class' );
```